# gcm how many devices can receive a push message at a time

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have about 1500 registration ID, i tried to send 1 push notification. But it didn't. Is it GCM does not allow sending to more than 1000 registration ID per message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. A single request to GCM can contain up to 1000 Registration IDs. You'll have to split your 1500 IDs into two separate requests.

Comment: thx, just found the exact paragraph on android website https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#send-msg`Target

Required. When your app server sends a message in GCM, it must specify a target.

For HTTP you must specify the target as one of:

registration_ids: For sending to 1 or more devices (up to 1000). When you send a message to multiple registration IDs, that is called a multicast message.
notification_key: For sending to multiple devices owned by a single user.`

Comment: @Eran I am using App Engine Endpoint with GCM. In my code in MessagingEndpoint class I got below lines List<RegistrationRecord> records = ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).limit(10).list();
        for (RegistrationRecord record : records) {

            //Original Code line
            Result result = sender.send(msg, record.getRegId(), 5);
...}  So can you please tell me how to split your 1500 IDs into two separate requests. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Google Docs:

GCM is support for up to 1,000 recipients for a single message. This capability makes it much easier to send out important messages to your entire user base. For instance, let's say you had a message that needed to be sent to 1,000,000 of your users, and your server could handle sending out about 500 messages per second. If you send each message with only a single recipient, it would take 1,000,000/500 = 2,000 seconds, or around half an hour. However, attaching 1,000 recipients to each message, the total time required to send a message out to 1,000,000 recipients becomes (1,000,000/1,000) / 500 = 2 seconds. This is not only useful, but important for timely data, such as natural disaster alerts or sports scores, where a 30 minute interval might render the information useless.

Taking advantage of this functionality is easy. If you're using the GCM helper library for Java, simply provide a List collection of registration IDs to the send or sendNoRetry method, instead of a single registration ID.